# Java coding censor words

Tags: java, bukkit

I am working on a Spigot plugin which is coded in Java and would like to censor player chat messages. I attempted to censor it using #replaceAll() but it censors more then it should

My code is (example word used)

```
public static String filter(String message) {
    return message.replaceAll("(?i)on", "**");
}
```

The outputs are
"turn it on" -> "turn it **"

but it also replaces 
"I did once" -> "I did **ce"

Is there a better method to do this that replaces it to the correct stars but doesn't get it if it's in the word.

Also if it possible to block it if they attempt to bypass using
"o n" or "o.n" I tried ignoring spaces but that triggered if they typed two actual words such as "to no" which would contain "on" without space.

Comment: Related: [How to implement decent “bad word filter”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225202/how-to-implement-decent-bad-word-filter/50225248#50225248)

Comment: This article is a pretty good read on the subject: https://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/

Answer (score 2):

You can change the regular expression to e.g., only match on word boundaries, using the `\b` flag:

```
text.replaceAll("\\bon\\b", "**");
```

(You need an extra backslash to escape the backslash or Java will treat it as a special character (probably backspace)).

That said, working with a regular expression will always give you poor results as your regular expressions don't understand the context. A natural language processing library (see the search engine of your choice) will be harder to use but get better results.

Comment: Using regex may be dangerous in a Minecraft Chat context, as players can do things like o.n, o.....n o..<dirty>..n